# Run console app in visual studio when file changes

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, visual-studio-2015, console-application

Is there a way in visual studio (2015) that when a file is changed i can exec a console app and pass the updated file name as an argument into the console app?

Comment: Do you mean any file on FS, files in your solution or just files open in editor? The last one is possible, first two could be hard to monitor.

Comment: Just when you edit a file in visual studio (e.g. I edit a html file inside visual studio i then need to do some manipulation a corresponding js file) it will fire off an exec

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to run your tool every time when the file changes?

Would you compromise to run it as a part of your build? Then you can do it easily.

In the Properties of that file, General - change "Exclude From Build" to "No". On the same page, change "Item Type" to "Custom Build Tool".

The "Custom Build Tool" item will be added to your "Configuration Properties" tree. Click on "General".

Specify the "Command Line", something like:

```
notepad.exe %(FullPath)
```

Also specify the "Outputs", like:

```
$(OutDir)
```

If you really need to run your tool on every save, you'd need to write a Visual Studio extension, handle "save" notification and run your tool from there.

Comment: 7 years late but I feel this should be accepted. Googling a similar problem lead me to this post describing the very useful custom build tool feature that I'd not heard of that provided a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the **DTE.Events.DocumentSaved** VS event and run your console app from it. For example, adjust the following Visual Commander extension:  [Run Cppcheck on the saved file](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#OnDocumentSaved).